# Command to remove all npm modules globally

Tags: node.js, npm

Is there a command to remove all global npm modules? If not, what do you suggest?

Answer (score 603, accepted):

The following command removes all global npm modules. Note: this does not work on Windows. For a working Windows version, see [Ollie Bennett's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15597395/1688034).

```
npm ls -gp --depth=0 | awk -F/ '/node_modules/ && !/\/npm$/ {print $NF}' | xargs npm -g rm
```

Here is how it works:

- `npm ls -gp --depth=0` lists all global top level modules (see the [cli documentation for ls](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls))
- `awk -F/ '/node_modules/ && !/\/npm$/ {print $NF}'` prints all modules that are not actually npm itself (does not end with `/npm`)
- `xargs npm -g rm` removes all modules globally that come over the previous pipe

Comment: Almost, need it on the `npm ls` command as well.  I tried to fix it myself but edits need to be at least 6 characters...

Comment: Will this command work under Ubuntu 12.04? I tried running the command as root user, and it still didn't work properly.

Comment: Not to be the awk golf guy, this can be done in a single awk command without grep:
`awk -F' |@' '/@/ {if ($(NF-1) != "npm") {print $(NF-1)}}'`

Explanation: split on spaces or @, only match lines with @, the module name will be the second to last match (`$(NF-1)`), so only print if it's not `npm`

Comment: I had to change the last `xargs npm -g rm` to `xargs npm -g uninstall` to get it to work on my machine

Comment: It didn't work on my Ubuntu system either, the tree was not removed (don't know why...). I tried a sed regex replacement too, and failed, but perl worked: npm -g ls | grep -v 'npm@' | perl -pe 's/[^[:ascii:]]//g;' | awk -F@ '{print $1}' | grep -v "/usr/local" | xargs sudo npm -g rm   (/usr/local appeared as the first line, had to remove it...)

Comment: Preview what this will remove by replacing ```xargs npm -g rm``` with ```xargs -L1 echo```.  I think the ```npm ls -gp``` at the beginning should be ```npm -ls -p```.

Comment: @fisherwebdev `npm ls -p` (ls not prefixed by dash) is correct

Comment: Warning: the new version doesn't filter out the npm module. You don't want to remove that one.

Comment: I also ran the new version without reading the comments.  ALWAYS READ THE COMMENTS.  Here is how to restore NPM:
curl https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sh

Comment: Recently the npm installer was removed, you need to reinstall node instead. On a Mac, with brew you can just do `brew update; brew upgrade node`.

Comment: `curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh` - I wasn't paying attention and missed the missing https:// when I copied from @Jack's answer. Also - https://gist.github.com/DanHerbert/9520689 (not me) is worth a note.

Comment: Wow. NPM doesn't make it easy to uninstall things. With bundler and gems, it's trivial to uninstall everything, the fact that you have to use grep and such is a horrible design. Is there a simpler way to do this? Who actually remembers the code required in the answer?

Comment: Might as well blow away your global `npm` and consider reinstalling it through `nvm install node`, see https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Comment: OMG, pipes, awk! This will not work from win cmd from-the-box.

Comment: @neverfox and others: Fixed, npm itself is no longer removed. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @KaiSternad I would double check? it seems to still have removed it on CentOS 7

Comment: This does not remove modules that have a / in the name, e.g. @angular/cli.

Comment: try the node cli library i wrote few months back, which will help in removing the all node_modules in the system. https://github.com/uttesh/mo

Answer (score 333):

For those using **Windows**, the easiest way to remove all globally installed npm packages is to delete the contents of:

`C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm`

You can get there quickly by typing `%appdata%/npm` in either the explorer, run prompt, or from the start menu.

Comment: Thanks for this one, what about npm-cache, should I remove that also?

Comment: don't delete the npm folder if it's there

Comment: In later versions of npm this seems to of moved to `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\npm` without the `roaming`.

Comment: I was reinstalling all packages, I ran into EINTEGRITY errors when running `npm install` again.  I had to delete my `package-lock.json` file as well.

Comment: for those in windows using scoop, the path is:
C:\Users\username\scoop\apps\nodejs\current\bin\node_modules

Comment: @Neil npm cache clean --force

Comment: If you are using nvm for windows, then your node_modules folder will be located at `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\nvm\[version]\node_modules`

Comment: I had to delete ```C:\Users\[username]\node_modules``` as well

Answer (score 185):

I tried [**Kai Sternad**'s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9283646/1202461) but it seemed imperfect to me. There was a lot of special symbols left after the last `awk` from the deps tree itself.

So, I came up with my own modification of **Kai Sternad**'s solution (with a little help from [cashmere's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22290968/1202461)):

```
npm ls -gp --depth=0 | awk -F/node_modules/ '{print $2}' | grep -vE '^(npm|)$' | xargs -r npm -g rm
```

`npm ls -gp --depth=0` lists all globally-installed npm modules in **parsable** format:

```
/home/leonid/local/lib
/home/leonid/local/lib/node_modules/bower
/home/leonid/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script
...
```

`awk -F/node_modules/ '{print $2}'` extracts module names from paths, forming the list of all globally-installed modules.

`grep -vE '^(npm|)$'` removes npm itself and blank lines.

`xargs -r npm -g rm` calls `npm -g rm` for each module in the list.

Like **Kai Sternad**'s solution, it'll only work under *nix.

Comment: Where are these files stored, I hate this method. Isn't there just a global package.json somewhere?

Comment: @EvanCarroll Nope, there is no such file, but `npm` installs all its global modules to the same directory. The exact location may vary, but typically it's `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`.

Comment: Just FYI, This one also removes npm

Comment: @BrDaHa hm, thanx, I'll check it. But it's strange since I'm explicitly filtering `npm`.

Comment: @BrDaHa just checked it on my ubuntu with npm `1.4.21` and it worked fine. Though, it attempted to remove `n` node binary manager and  `node-gyp` addon builder, but not `npm`.

Comment: I was using this command on OSX Mavericks. Nbd, I was reinstalling all of node anyway :)

Comment: This command will return an error if there are no modules other than npm installed (it does not return code 0 for a 'perfect' pre-existing condition).

Comment: @dps thanx! Now it should work fine even if there are no modules other than npm installed.

Comment: This command works on OSX and doesn't remove npm `npm ls -gp --depth=0 | awk -F/node_modules/ '{print $2}' | grep -vE '^(npm)$' | xargs npm -g rm`

Comment: grep wasn't working complaining about empty sub patterns. Also npm errors were not being filtered out. This fixes that (using OS X): `npm ls -gp --depth=0 --silent | awk -F/node_modules/ '{print $2}' | sed '/^$/d; /^npm$/d;' | xargs npm -g rm` -- decided to use sed instead

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny I changed and corrected my answer, would you please change yours accordingly ? Thanks.

Comment: @KaiSternad I've tried both our solutions with several `node`/`npm` versions. `npm` module was efficiently filtered out every time. I also failed to see any difference from your last edit. I guess people comply about `npm` being removed because `npm@3` flattens dependency tree, so both our solutions may remove some of it's dependencies, thus breaking it.

Comment: This command failed to handle scoped package (like `@angular/cli`). I add another matcher for `awk` and the working command for me looks like this: `npm ls -gp --depth=0 | awk -F/ '/node_modules\/@/ {print $(NF-1)"/"$NF} /node_modules\/[^@]/ && !/\/npm$/ {print $NF}'  | xargs npm -g rm`

Answer (score 81):

```
sudo npm list -g --depth=0. | awk -F ' ' '{print $2}' | awk -F '@' '{print $1}'  | sudo xargs npm remove -g
```

worked for me

- `sudo npm list -g --depth=0.`  lists all top level installed
- `awk -F ' ' '{print $2}'` gets rid of ├──
- `awk -F '@' '{print $1}'` gets the part before '@'
- `sudo xargs npm remove -g` removes the package globally

Comment: This version worked best for me as of June '14. The only addition could be to filter out "UNMET" dependencies from the list, but that's not critical, as `npm remove UNMET` simply does NOOP.

Comment: would add `grep -v npm` so that npm itself don't get removed: `sudo npm list -g --depth=0. | grep -v npm | awk -F ' ' '{print $2}' | awk -F '@' '{print $1}'  | sudo xargs npm remove -g`

Comment: there it goes, your npm!

Comment: Even here in 2023 on a new M2 this helped me sort out some weird problems trying to build a project.

Answer (score 32):

For those using **Powershell**:

```
npm -gp ls --depth=0 | ForEach-Object { Get-Item $_ } | Where { $_.Name -ne 'npm' } | ForEach-Object { npm rm -g $_.Name }
```

To clear the cache:

```
npm cache clear
```

Answer (score 26):

Just switch into your `%appdata%/npm` directory and run the following...

```
for package in `ls node_modules`; do npm uninstall $package; done;
```

***EDIT: This command breaks with npm 3.3.6 (Node 5.0). I'm now using the following Bash command, which I've mapped to npm_uninstall_all in my .bashrc file:***

```
npm uninstall `ls -1 node_modules | tr '/\n' ' '`
```

Added bonus? it's way faster!

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10187

[How do you uninstall all dependencies listed in package.json (NPM)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19106284/how-do-you-uninstall-all-dependencies-listed-in-package-json-npm/24396148#24396148)

Comment: Love this. Faster and simple :) I just used grep -v `npm` and `n` before the `tr`

Answer (score 22):

If you would like to remove all the packages that you have installed, you can use the `npm -g ls` command to find them, and then `npm -g rm` to remove them.

Answer (score 20):

in windows go to
"C:\Users{username}\AppData\Roaming"  directory and manually remove npm folder

Comment: This was straightforward/useful for us on Windows here. Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

If you have [jq](https://stedolan.github.com/jq) installed, you can go even without grep/awk/sed:

```
npm ls -g --json --depth=0 |
  jq -r '.dependencies|keys-["npm"]|join("\n")' |
  xargs npm rm -g
```

On Debian and derived you can install [jq](https://stedolan.github.com/jq) with:

```
sudo apt-get install jq
```

Comment: This is a solid answer with an apropos `json` style.

Comment: If sudo is required then: `npm ls -g --json --depth=0 | jq -r '.dependencies|keys-["npm"]|join("\n")' | xargs sudo npm rm -g`

Answer (score 5):

OS not specified by OP. For **Windows**, this script can be used to nuke the local and the user's global modules and cache.

I noticed on **linux** that the global root is truly global to the system instead of the given user. So deleting the global root might not be a good idea for a shared system. That aside, I can port the script to *bash* if interested.

For **Windows**, save to a cmd file to run.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion 
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions

SET /A ecode=0

:: verify
SET /P conf="About to delete all global and local npm modules and clear the npm cache. Continue (y/[n])?
IF /I NOT "%conf%"=="y" (
  ECHO operation aborted
  SET /A ecode=!ecode!+1
  GOTO END
)

:: wipe global and local npm root
FOR %%a IN ("" "-g") DO (

  :: get root path into var
  SET cmd=npm root %%~a
  FOR /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%r IN (`!cmd!`) DO (SET npm_root=%%r)

  :: paranoid
  ECHO validating module path "!npm_root!"
  IF "!npm_root:~-12!"=="node_modules" (
    IF NOT EXIST "!npm_root!" (
      ECHO npm root does not exist "!npm_root!"
    ) ELSE (
      ECHO deleting "!npm_root!" ...
      :: delete
      RMDIR /S /Q "!npm_root!"
    )
  ) ELSE (
      ECHO suspicious npm root, ignoring "!npm_root!"
  )
)

:: clear the cache
ECHO clearing the npm cache ...
call npm cache clean

:: done
ECHO done

:END

ENDLOCAL & EXIT /b %ecode%
```

Answer (score 4):

All you done good job. This is combined suggestions in to one line code.

```
npm rm -g `npm ls -gp --depth=0 | awk -F/node_modules/ '{print $2}' | tr '/\n' ' '`
```

What is different? Uninstall will be done in single command like: `npm rm -g *** *** ***`

Answer (score 4):

For `yarn global`

```sh
nano ~/.config/yarn/global/package.json
<Manually remove all packages from package.json>
yarn global add
```

Or, if you don't care about what is actually inside `package.json`

```sh
echo {} >  ~/.config/yarn/global/package.json && yarn global add
```

This should apply to NPM too, but I am not exactly sure where NPM global is stored.

Answer (score 3):

For a more manual approach that doesn't involve an file explorers, doesn't care where the installation is, is very unlikely to break at a later date, and is 100% cross-platform compatible, and feels a lot safer because of the extra steps, use this one.

- `npm ls -g --depth=0`
- Copy output
- Paste into favorite code editor (I use vsCode.  Great multi-cursor editing)
- Check for any packages you'd like to keep (nodemon, yarn, to name a few)  Remove those lines
- Remove every instance of `+--` or other line decorators
- Remove all the version information (eg '`@2.11.4`')
- Put all items on same line, space separated
- Add `npm uninstall -g`  to beginning of that one line.

  - Mine looks like `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli @vue/cli express-generator jest mocha typescript bindings nan nodemon yarn`, but I didn't install many packages globally on this machine.
- Copy line
- Paste in terminal, hit enter if not already added from the copy/paste
- Look for any errors in the terminal.
- Check `npm ls -g` to make sure it's complete.  If something got reinstalled, rinse and repeat

The other cli-only approaches are great for computer administrators doing something for 100 near-identical computers at once from the same ssh, or maybe a Puppet thing.  But if you're only doing this once, or even 5 times over the course of a year, this is much easier.

Answer (score 2):

You can locate your all installed npm packages at the location:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

and delete the content of npm which you want to remove.

If AppData is not showing, it means it is hidden and you can go to View in file explorer and checked the Hidden items then there you can see all the hidden folders.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows:

```
rmdir /s /q "%appdata%/npm"
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are on windows, and want to remove/uninstall all node_modules then you need to do following steps.

1. Go to windows command prompt
2. Navigate to node_modules directory (**Not inside node_modules folder**)
3. Type below command and give it for 1-2 minutes it will uninstall all  directories inside node_module

   ```
    rmdir /s /q node_modules
   ```

Hope this will help some one on windows

Answer (score 1):

if you have Intellij Webstorm you can use its built-in graphical package manager.

open it as root and create an emtpy project. go to

> File > Settings > Language and Frameworks > Node.js and NPM

there you will see all the installed packages. Uninstalling is easy, you can select and deselect any package you want to uninstall, Ctrl+a woks as well.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use below for MAC,

> sudo rm -rf
> /usr/local/{bin/{node,npm},lib/node_modules/npm,lib/node,share/man/*/node.*}

Answer (score 1):

```
npm list -g
```

will show you the location of globally installed packages.

> If you want to output them to a file:
> npm list -g > ~/Desktop/npmoutputs.txt

```
npm rm -g
```

will remove them

Answer (score 1):

Try this and tell me what you think

```
npx npkill
```

Comment: This is the most convinient way to do that in 2023.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to uninstall any package:

```
npm rm -g <package_name>
```

Comment: The question clearly said ALL, not a specific package name.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm ls -gp | awk -F/ '/node_modules/&&!/node_modules.*node_modules/&&!/npm/{print $NF}' | xargs npm rm -g
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is the top answer in search I'm posting this here as it was the solution I used in the past to clean the computer switching laptops.

```sh
cd ~/Documents # or where you keep your projects
find . -name "node_modules" -exec rm -rf '{}' +
```

source: https://winsmarts.com/delete-all-node-modules-folders-recursively-on-windows-edcc9a9c079e

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more elegant solution that I tried where I let npm do all the work for me.

```
# On Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon
# First navigate to where your global packages are installed.

$ npm root # returns /where/your/node_modules/folder/is
$ cd /where/your/node_modules/folder/is # i.e for me it was cd /home/user/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules
```

Then if you do `npm uninstall` or `npm remove` these modules will be treated as if they were normal dependencies of a project. It even generates a package-lock.json file when it is done:

```
$ npm remove <package-name> # you may need sudo if it was installed using sudo
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have have MSYS for Windows:

```
rm -rf ${APPDATA//\\/\/}/npm
```

Answer (score 0):

The npm README.md states:

> If you would like to remove all the packages that you have installed,
> then you can use the `npm ls` command to find them, and then `npm rm` to
> remove them.
>
> To remove cruft left behind by npm 0.x, you can use the included
> `clean-old.sh` script file.  You can run it conveniently like this:
>
> ```sh
>    npm explore npm -g -- sh scripts/clean-old.sh
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In macOS, I believe you can simply delete the .npm-global folder in your User directory.

.npm and .npm-global folders in macOS User directory:
[image: .npm and .npm-global folders in macOS User directory]

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo npm uninstall npm -g
```

Or, if that fails, get the npm source code, and do:

```
sudo make uninstall
```

To remove everything npm-related manually:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/{lib/node{,/.npm,_modules},bin,share/man}/npm*
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [NVM for Windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows), you need to delete all the modules that you don't want inside `node_modules` of the Node.js with the version that contains the global modules you want to remove. **Do not remove `corepack` and `npm` packages** as they are necessary for Node.js.

The folder can be located in:

- `%USERPROFILE%\.nvm\{version}\node_modules`.

  - `%USERPROFILE%` is your user folder.
  - `{version}` is the version of Node.js where you want to delete its global modules.

  Example: `C:\Users\Cappuccino\.nvm\19.8.1\node_modules`.
- `{installationPath}\{version}\node_modules`.

  - `{installationPath}` is where you have installed NVM for Windows.
  - `{version}` is the version of Node.js where you want to delete its global modules.
    Example: `D:\Programs\NVM\v19.8.1\node_modules`.

Answer (score -1):

sed solution

```
npm -gp ls | sed -r '/npm$|(node_modules.*){2,}/d; s:.*/([^/]+)$:\1:g' | xargs npm rm -g
```

Answer (score -5):

Just put in your console:

sudo npm list -g --depth=0. | awk -F ' ' '{print $2}' | awk -F '@' '{print $1}'  | sudo xargs npm remove -g

Its work for me...

Comment: Exact copt of solution already mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22290968/957731), on this very same page.