# How can I uninstall npm modules in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, npm

As commonly known, any npm module can be installed by running a simple command: `npm install <module_name>`.

I have installed a few modules that I do not use any more and I just want to get them off. I have a few questions regarding this:

- Do we have any command or process to uninstall a module from the root (something like `npm uninstall <module_name>`)
  or will simply removing the module files do?
- How does it affect us if we keep the unused modules?

Comment: If you want to remove all npm modules, go here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283472/command-to-remove-all-npm-modules-globally/9283646#9283646

Answer (score 2055, accepted):

The command is simply `npm uninstall <name>`

The Node.js documents https://npmjs.org/doc/ have all the commands that you need to know with npm.

A local install will be in the `node_modules/` directory of your application. This won't affect the application if a module remains there with no references to it.

If you're removing a global package, however, any applications referencing it will crash.

Here are different options:

`npm uninstall <name>` removes the module from `node_modules` but does not update `package.json`

`npm uninstall <name> --save` also removes it from `dependencies`in `package.json`

`npm uninstall <name> --save-dev` also removes it from `devDependencies` in `package.json`

`npm uninstall -g <name> --save` also removes it globally

Comment: try this `npm -g ls | grep -v 'npm@' | awk '/@/ {print $2}' | awk -F@ '{print $1}' | xargs npm -g rm` to uninstall all gobally installed module. if you are on windows then you need to install Cygwin or git to run it

Comment: @nmrony's command should work for Mac users too.  I used it in Yosemite, but had to `cd /usr/local/lib` and then change the last statement to `xargs npm uninstall`.

Comment: For some reason I cannot use "npm uninstall ___" or even "sudo npm uninstall ___". I do not have privileges to remove the files. I can only remove npm packages by going to the directory and force removing everything by hand. (using rm in the terminal). How to fix this?

Comment: Global modules are stored in the `node_modules` directory in the node installation root directory. If you don't want to run a lengthy command, just delete the module directories from there. Don't just blindly nuke everything though.... npm is a module in that directory too!

Comment: For uninstalling all global modules:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926672/where-does-npm-install-packages

And delete node_modules folder

For uninstalling all local modules delete local node_modules folder

Comment: Also you can use `npm list -g --depth=0` to get the globally installed npm modules.

Comment: @IshikawaYoshi, yes by going to the path: /usr/local/lib/ there you will find node_modules folder, by deleting it, it will clear everything.

Comment: alias include: un, unlink, remove, rm, r
    `npm r <module>`

Comment: I have tried to remove cypress@3.1.4 using all the commands listed above, & it is still there

Comment: `npm uninstall <name> now removes the module from both `package.json` and `node_modules`

Comment: I tried to `npm uninstall package@version` too and it didn't work. It did work when I did `npm uninstall package` (without the `@version`) cc @SteveStaple (as noted in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52990522/363701)

Comment: as of 2019, node 13 (I believe 10+ as well) removes packages from package.json via `npm uninstall <name>`

Comment: As comments and an answer mention, the `--save` flag is no longer useful as it is the default behavior without the flag; if you want the old default behavior (leaving package.json untouched), use the `--no-save` flag. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Comment: I just test it without `--save`, and for sure `package.json` get updated.
`node -v
v12.13.0
npm -v
6.13.0`

Answer (score 95):

If it doesn't work with `npm uninstall <module_name>` try it globally by typing `-g`.

Maybe you just need to do it as an superUser/administrator with `sudo npm uninstall <module_name>`.

Comment: `-g` is helpful if there is a `npm WARN uninstall`.

Answer (score 60):

Well, to give a complete answer to this question, there are [two methods](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/uninstalling-local-packages) (for example we call the installed module as module1):

1. To remove module1 **without** changing package.json:

   `npm uninstall module1`
2. To remove module1 **with** changing package.json, and removing it from the dependencies in package.json:

   `npm uninstall --save module1`

Note: to simplify the above mentioned commands, you can use **-S** instead of **--save** , and can use **remove**, **rm**, **r**, **un**, **unlink** instead of **uninstall**

Comment: For the sake of completeness, one should be careful does he/she wanna remove the GLOBAL or LOCAL dependancy. For globals use -g with the above!

Also:
For uninstalling all global modules:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926672/where-does-npm-install-packages

And delete node_modules folder

For uninstalling all local modules delete local node_modules folder

Comment: If anyone is silly like me you might also want to check that you're running `npm uninstall ...` from the correct directory as well!

Answer (score 32):

I just install *stylus* by default under my home dir, so I just use `npm uninstall stylus` to detach it, or you can try `npm rm <package_name>` out.

Answer (score 30):

To uninstall the Node.js module:

```
npm uninstall <module_name>
```

This will remove the module from folder *node_modules*, but not from file *package.json*. So when we do npm install again it will download the module.

So to remove the module from file *package.json*, use:

```
npm uninstall <module_name> --save
```

This also deletes the dependency from file *package.json*.

And if you want to uninstall any globally module you can use:

```
npm -g uninstall <module_name> --save
```

This will delete the dependency globally.

Answer (score 20):

To remove packages in folder *node_modules* in bulk, you could also remove them from file *package.json*, save it, and then run `npm prune` in the terminal.

This will remove those packages, which exist in the file system, but are not used/declared in file *package.json*.

P.S.: This is particularly useful on Windows, as you may often encounter problems with being unable to delete some files due to the "exceeded path length limit".

Answer (score 13):

Sometimes `npm uninstall -g packageName` doesn’t work.

In this case you can delete package manually.

On Mac, go to folder `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` and delete the folder with the package you want. That's it. Check your list of globally installed packages with this command:

```
npm list -g --depth=0
```

Comment: Just curious, why doesn't "npm uninstall -g packageName" work in some cases ?

Comment: because it's huge buggy code... it really difficult to adapt to every OS version. I think that's is the reason

Comment: It really saved my time! don't know why  "npm uninstall -g packageName"  do not work.

Answer (score 9):

Update for npm 5:

As of [npm 5.0.0](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/161081169345/v500), installed/uninstalled modules are added/removed as a dependency by default, so the `--save` option is no longer needed.

Run

```
npm uninstall <package>
```

For example:

```
npm uninstall mongodb
```

It will remove the module from the *node_modules* folder and also the *package.json* file.

Comment: True; if you want the old default behavior (leaving package.json untouched), use the --no-save flag https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Comment: this answer and this comment should be way up

Answer (score 9):

Alias can be used to to uninstall node_modules package

`un` alias for `uninstall`

- removes single package

```
 - npm un <PACKAGE_NAME>
```

- removes multiple packages by adding space between packages names

```
- npm un <PACKAGE_NAME_1> <PACKAGE_NAME_2>
```

- removes all `node_modules` packages

```
 - rm -rf node_modules/
```

Comment: Is the `rm -rf ...` command for Linux or Unix? I'm on Windows, it won't seem to work for me, I get an error `A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'rf'`

Answer (score 8):

You can also run the following as shorthand:

`npm un packageName` or `npm rm packageName`

Note: Add `-g` at end of command to uninstall global packages.

Answer (score 6):

I found this out the hard way, even if it is *seemingly* obvious.

I initially tried to loop through the *node_modules* directory running `npm uninstall module-name` with a simple for loop in a script. I found out it will not work if you call the full path, e.g.,

```
npm uninstall module-name
```

was working, but

```
npm uninstall /full/path/to/node_modules/module-name
```

was not working.

Answer (score 6):

For Windows users - if you want to remove all the Node.js modules installed at once:

- Open a PowerShell window
- Go inside the *node_modules* folder (`cd node_modules`)
- Run this command - "npm uninstall (Get-ChildItem).Name"

It will uninstall all the modules.

Answer (score 6):

Simply,

```
npm un module_name
```

OR

```
npm uninstall module_name
```

Make sure you uninstall it in the same directory as the package.json and node_modules folder.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Log in as root (might be required depending on install)
su -

# List all global packages
npm ls -g --depth=0

# List all local (project) packages
npm ls -p --depth=0

# Remove all global packages
npm ls -g --depth=0 | awk -F/ '/node_modules/ && !/\/npm$/ {print $NF}' | xargs npm -g rm

# Remove all local packges
npm ls -p --depth=0 | awk -F/ '/node_modules/ && !/\/npm$/ {print $NF}' | xargs npm -p rm

# NOTE (optional): to use node with sudo you can add the bins to /usr/bin
# NOTE $PATHTONODEINSTALL is where node is installed (e.g. /usr/local/node)
sudo ln -s $PATHTONODEINSTALL/bin/node /usr/bin/node
sudo ln -s $PATHTONODEINSTALL/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm
```

Answer (score 2):

The `uninstall` option didn't work for me when I tried to use the same command to the one I used in installing (as I was installing with the `@latest` directive)

So for example, I installed a package like this:

```
npm install  @ngtools/webpack@latest
```

And then I wanted to uninstall it, so I used the same command (including @latest):

```
npm uninstall  @ngtools/webpack@latest
```

So the above uninstall didn't work. I have to remove the `@latest`, and then it worked well:

```
npm uninstall  @ngtools/webpack
```

Answer (score 2):

To uninstall a module using npm, you can use:

```
npm uninstall moduleName
```

Also, if you want to uninstall and want the change to be reflected in your package.json then you can use the --save flag, like this:

```
npm uninstall moduleName --save
OR
npm uninstall -S
```

And if you want to uninstall a module from devDependencies and want the change to be reflected in package.json then you can use -D flag, like this:

```
npm uninstall moduleName -D
```

Answer (score 2):

In **`npm v6+`** `npm uninstall <package_name>` removes it both in folder *node_modules* and file *package.json*.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, if you've started using `yarn`, in place of `npm`:
`yarn remove <package-name>`

Is the equivalent of:
`npm uninstall <package-name> --save`

This will
  - remove the package from `package.json`, as well as
  - uninstall it from your project's `node-modules` folder

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is:

```
npm uninstall packageName --save-dev
```

See upper level packages names in the your project:

```
npm list --depth=0
```

The output will be like:

```
app@0.1.0 /home/jackkobec/projects/myAppName
├── packageName@packageVersion
├── express@4.16.4
```

Copy package name and execute npm uninstall command. Example for express package:

```
npm uninstall express --save-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to uninstall an specific package using npm,
you can use the following command :

Sintax:

```
npm uninstall <package-name>
```

Example:

```
npm uninstall moment
```

Comment: If you can keep the config in your package.json file in the dependencies property , you need to use the following command: npm uninstall webpack --no-save

Comment: Why did you post this answer when there were already many other answers saying the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to uninstall a number of modules, then just run the `npm uninstall`.

Then go to file *package.json* and delete the unwanted module from there, and then just run the command `npm install`. It should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are on Windows, run CMD as administrator and type:

```
npm -g uninstall <package name>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete a Node.js module manually. For Windows,

1. Go to the `node_modules` directory of your repository.
2. Delete the Node.js module you don't want.
3. Don't forget to remove the reference to the module in your *package.json* file! Your project may still run with the reference, but you may get an error. You also don't want to leave unused references in your *package.json* file that can cause confusion later.