# After completely uninstalling nodejs when I run npm config ls command, I can still see proxy I set earlier

Tags: node.js, npm

I am not able to install packages using npm. I keep getting error shown in below image.
[image]

Using [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066532/how-to-uninstall-npm-modules-in-node-js), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x)  I uninstalled nodejs. After installing the nodejs again, when I run `npm config ls` command, I can still see proxy details which I added earlier.

**How can I ensure that when I uninstall nodejs it also removes all the config files.**

Comment: uninstaling node doesn't do anything to npm, since it is an own package. you should check the files as in https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-config.html#npmrc-Files and remove your setting there

Answer (score 0):

I was setting proxy as

```
npm config set http_proxy=http://myproxy address:8080
```

which is wrong now I use

```
npm config set proxy http://myproxy address:8080
```

and I am able to install packages.