# How do you uninstall Bower (the package manager)?

Tags: uninstallation, bower, package-managers, bower-install

How do you uninstall Bower? I mean the package manager, not the packages (that I have already uninstalled).

Comment: `npm install -g bower`

Comment: It depends how you installed bower in the first place.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To uninstall global package :

```
npm uninstall -g bower
```

See this thread : [how to uninstall npm modules in node js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066532/how-to-uninstall-npm-modules-in-node-js)

Comment: I got a bunch of errors with npm ERR!... How can I bypass them and force to uninstall properly?

Comment: Are you root when you launch the cmd ? Try with sudo before.

Comment: Yes I typed sudo -s before the command line before to uninstall Bower. And I just got **bash-3.2#** as answer from the Terminal after typing my password (and before to uninstall Bower).

Comment: First I was not root, so I got an error from Bower asking me to log as root. Then, I got other errors from Bower when I tried again to uninstall. Now I got **npm WARN uninstall not installed in /usr/local/lib/node_modules** as error: "bower": what does it mean?

Comment: It means bower is uninstall globally : try `bower -v` -> if it show an error, bower is not here anymore.

Comment: I got **-bash: bower: command not found**: thanks, it works :-)

Comment: Great. Can you please set your question as answered.

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo npm uninstall -g bower
```

**Sudo:** to do it as an superUser/administrator

**-g :** to try it globally

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo npm uninstall -g bower
sudo npm remove -g bower
sudo npm rm -g bower
```

npm Uninstall aliases remove, rm, r, un, unlink [reference](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/uninstall)

Comment: Can you elaborate the steps?

Comment: In mentioned 3 lines(commands), you can use any one of 'em to uninstall the bower. remove, rm, r, un, unlike are "uninstall alias". does it make sense?