# npm: using 'npm uninstall' vs. just removing the folder

Tags: npm

I wanted to try grunt-babel, so I opened up a terminal in my Home folder and did npm install --save-dev grunt-babel babel-preset-es2015 according to the plugin's instructions.

I was doing this too hastily, and realized I should probably have done this in my *new* project folder where I am dabbling with ES6 code. I had not even done npm init in that folder nor in the Home folder from where I executed the install command.

When I do npm uninstall grunt-babel, the preset files are removed but 91 folders of different dependencies remain in the node_modules folder.

Can I simply remove the folder instead of running npm uninstall 91 times?

This guy asked a similar question but none of the answers address his subquestion of just removing the folder: [how to uninstall npm modules in node js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066532/how-to-uninstall-npm-modules-in-node-js)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

- `npm uninstall <name>` removes the module from node_modules, but not package.json.
- `npm uninstall <name> --save` to also delete the dependency from package.json.
- `npm rm <package_name>` removes the packages when uninstall not working
- `npm prune <name>` ([see docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/prune)) for extraneous packages and packages that are not listed on the parent package's dependencies list.

If you don't want to uninstall one by one run
`rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean && npm install`
It's a good way for being sure the packages you uninstall are no more in the packages json.

Now in 2021 `npm uninstall <name>` will also removed it from package.json

Comment: How does that answer the question of manual removing and npm uninstall difference .It's good you added types of removal but can you please give specific answer

Comment: `npm uninstall <name>` DOES remove it from package.json in 2021. Can someone update this answer?

Answer (score 21):

**UPDATED answer (2020):**

These are all aliases to `uninstall`:
`remove`, `rm`, `r`, `un`, `unlink`

And today there is no need for `--save` flag since it is the default. The same goes for install BTW.

Comment: "2020" is useless, as I might be on npm 4 in 2020. For what version of npm are you sure what you wrote is true?

Comment: Don't know the exact version, but can safely say npm v7

Answer (score 1):

Use `npm list` as a tool to understand your changes. I usually use the time to make a capture file like:

```
npm list >1307
```

do some change

```
npm list >1309
```

so then:

```
cat 13??
```

or an editor lets me see what npm *thinks* it did.

For uninstall, only packages on the root all size of 'whole package' get removed. Other then that, the command is politely ignored...

For example:

```
├── safe-stable-stringify@1.1.0
├── semver@6.3.0
├─┬ tableify@1.1.0
│ └─┬ optimist@0.6.1
│   ├── minimist@0.0.8 deduped
│   └── wordwrap@0.0.3
```

safe-stable-stringify is a removal candidate, but wordwrap is not. Think about it, this is entirely reasonable !

```
npm uninstall pkgtoyank -save
```

updates packages.json by removing it from there as well.

npm is very well designed to say the least. I usually hugely avoid directly poking under it in ./node_modules I will copy things out from there to look at them, but why yank on a leash of a *BIG CAT* and get bit. it works; use it as its intended....