# How to solve react webpack problem with npm-start

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

Here is my error page:

> There might be a problem with the project dependency tree. It is
>   likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix
>   locally.
>
> The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a
>   dependency:
>
> "webpack": "4.19.1"
>
> Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it
>   automatically. However, a different version of webpack was detected
>   higher up in the tree:
>
> C:\Users\Acer\node_modules\webpack (version: 4.28.3)
>
> Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause
>   hard-to-debug issues.
>
> If you would prefer to ignore this check, add
>   SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project. That will
>   permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.
>
> To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact
>   order:
>
> 1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
> 2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
> 3. Remove "webpack" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
> 4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.
>
> In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem. If this has
>   not helped, there are a few other things you can try:
>
> 5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
>       This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.
> 6. Check if C:\Users\Acer\node_modules\webpack is outside your project directory.
>       For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.
> 7. Try running npm ls webpack in your project folder.
>       This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed webpack.
>
> If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file
>   in your project. That would permanently disable this preflight check
>   in case you want to proceed anyway.
>
> P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-)
>   We hope you find them helpful!
>
> ```
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! first-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the first-app@0.1.0 start script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-01-03T12_30_23_160Z-debug.log
> ```

I've applied all steps but, npm start command still doesn't work.
What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read : https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and  https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. You may need to format your question a little bit highlighting what is the exact problem and what you are expecting.

Comment: Have you tried what's suggested [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5972#issuecomment-449831383).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066532/how-to-uninstall-npm-modules-in-node-js I just solved it using instructions on this link !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NPM start returns error, "There might be a problem with the project dependency tree"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56528222/npm-start-returns-error-there-might-be-a-problem-with-the-project-dependency-t)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I got the solution! Focus on the point 6: it asks to delete node_modules folder outside your project directory.

So, I deleted my `C:\Users\Acer\node_modules` folder and `npm start` worked for me !!

Comment: Anyway to accomplish this without deleting the folder though?

Answer (score 3):

It is due to the node module dependency conflict.

Delete the `node_modules` folder from `C:\Users\Acer directory`. It will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tested many ways including delete the node_modules folder but it didn't work , perhaps the best one is to delete the current version of node.js and reinstall it..it answered for me ,i hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by switching from npm to yarn

Just delete the `node_moduels`folder and the `package-lock.json` file (not the package.json file). After that just try `yarn` to install all the packages and here you go.

installation for yarn:
https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#windows-stable

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `C:\Users\` Delete any node_modules folders outside its parent projects folder in the directory folder. Worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

must have to follow all these steps :

1. curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_13.x -o nodesource_setup.sh #installation purpose.
2. sudo bash nodesource_setup.sh
3. sudo apt-get install nodejs -y
4. sudo apt update
5. sudo apt-get update
6. npm install -g create-react-app
7. create-react-app --version
8. create-react-app hello-react

happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

I've created a .env file and then I added this command==> SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true
to the .env file! It works for me!

Comment: While this would prevent the error, it doesn't really solve the original problem posted as the original author did not state that they wanted to skip the check altogether.