# (react-native-svg Error) "Tried to register two views with the same name RNSVGRect"

Tags: reactjs, react-native

react-native-svg produces error: "Tried to register two views with the same name RNSVGRect"

I have react native projects and I want to use SVGs in them.

I started the projects using EXPO. I am using yarn and npm to add modules.

I get an error message: "Tried to register two views with the same name RNSVGRect" when all I do is try to import Svg from react-native-svg

```
import React from "react";
import Svg from "react-native-svg";
```

Comment: found same issue on my React Native project Android and Ios. I am using clean Script to clear it, inside the package.json --> scripts.
"cleanRNSVG": "find ./node_modules -type d -mindepth 2 -name react-native-svg -exec rm -rf {} \\;"

Answer (score 21):

In my case the problem was the following:

In my package.json in the root folder there was `react-native-svg : 12.12.1`.

I got this error message when I tried to use walletConnect Provider component. This library had `node_modules/@walletConnect/react-native-dapp/node_modules/package.json`. In there there was `"react-native-svg": "^9.6.4"`

So I just changed the version of my root   react-native-svg to the same version as the one from walletConnect. The error message was gone.

Comment: Watch out for `node_modules/@walletConnect/react-native-qrcode-svg/node_modules/package.json` too!

Comment: Instead of downgrading my own library, I overwrite walletconnect's lib, because you cannot patch lib deps.

What I've done was rename `react-native-svg` in package.json file and point it to the last commit: `"react-native-svg-gg": "react-native-svg/react-native-svg#54e40251a491bb1a2d0a75e4748a23ea24fb3f6b"`.
After that I overright every library in metro.config.js:
`extraNodeModules: {
      'react-native-svg': path.resolve(
        __dirname,
        './node_modules/react-native-svg-gg'
      ),
    },`

Answer (score 10):

### Update:

For Expo 34, 35, 36, 37

Expo managed apps now require you to install `react-native-svg` using

```
expo install react-native-svg
```

This is then used in the following way:

```
import * as Svg from 'react-native-svg';
```

Here is an example

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Svg, { Circle, Rect } from 'react-native-svg';

export default class SvgExample extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFill, { alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }]}>
        <Svg height="50%" width="50%" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <Circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" stroke="blue" strokeWidth="2.5" fill="green" />
          <Rect x="15" y="15" width="70" height="70" stroke="red" strokeWidth="2" fill="yellow" />
        </Svg>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

It is always best to check the documentation for the correct installation steps as SO questions can go out of date. You can find more about svgs in Expo [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/svg/).

---

### Previous Answer for older version of Expo

You cannot use `react-native-svg` with `Expo` as it requires linking. `Expo` already includes `react-native-svg` so by adding it as a dependency and then importing it you are causing it to get confused.

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/svg/

To use svg in expo you can just import it as follows

```
import { Svg } from 'expo'
```

You should remove `react-native-svg` from your `package.json` and your `package-lock.json`

You can do this by running `npm uninstall —-save react-native-svg`

You can see more about uninstalling dependencies here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13066677/5508175

Once you have uninstalled the dependency you should do the following:

1. Remove the `node_modules` folder
2. Close down all windows that are open for expo
3. Delete the `package-lock.json`
4. Run `npm i`
5. Restart expo with `expo start -c`

Answer (score 5):

For my Expo managed app, I was able to solve this issue by using [yarn resolutions](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/) in my `package.json`.

```
"resolutions": {
  "react-native-svg": "12.3.0"  
},
```

If you are using npm use "[overrides](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides)" instead

```
"overrides": {
  "react-native-svg": "12.3.0"  
},
```

Answer (score 2):

Try running
npm dedupe
It worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was the following:

In my package.json in the root folder there was react-native-svg : ^9.6.4.

I got this error message when I tried to use walletConnect Provider component. This library had node_modules/@walletConnect/react-native-dapp/node_modules/package.json. In there there was "react-native-svg": "^9.6.4"

So i just did  **npm uninstall —-save react-native-svg**
and than deleted the node_modules
after it
1). npm install --legacy-peer-deps
2). npx rn-nodeify --install --hack
3). uninstall the old build
4). npx react-native run-android
5). npm install react-native-svg
6). npx react-native run-android

error was hone