# How to remove eslint plugin eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I have eslint (of Airbnb coding style) setup for my React project, which has dependency of "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y", which I do not want for my current project.

My question how to remove this specific plugin "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y".

When I uninstall "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y" it gives error following error:

"Failed to load plugin jsx-a11y: Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y'"

Is there any way to solve above issue ?

Comment: go to '/path-to/node_modules' and check "eslint-plugin" is there are not?? in "package.json" alsoo. This link might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066532/how-to-uninstall-npm-modules-in-node-js

Comment: eslint-disable plugin you can find here. https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-disable

Comment: First install package `eslint-config-airbnb-base` which will give you the base eslint airbnb package and then install `eslint-plugin-react`. This way you don't have to install `eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y`. Hope that helps!!

Comment: Sure I will try this, Thanks !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer of Alberto Perez is valid if you include `jsx-a11y` plugin explicitly. But if you extend another plugin that contains `jsx-a11y` his approach doesn't work.

If so you can use this:

## 1st solution

https://github.com/mradionov/eslint-plugin-disable

At the moment it doesn't support `eslint@8`.
See the [issue](https://github.com/mradionov/eslint-plugin-disable/issues/35).

## 2nd solution

https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/2032#issuecomment-568934232

```js
const a11yOff = Object.keys(require('eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y').rules)
    .reduce((acc, rule) => { acc[`jsx-a11y/${rule}`] = 'off'; return acc }, {})

module.exports = {
    rules: {
        ...a11yOff,
        // your rules
    },
}
```

Comment: awesome, good to find this

Answer (score 7):

First of all, you will need to remove the references to the plugin (`eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y`) on your `.eslintrc` (That's why when you uninstall it you eslint config is giving you an error):

1. Search and delete in `extends` (if you have it) `plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended`.
2. Search and delete in `plugins`: `jsx-a11y`.
3. Then in `rules` delete every rule that involes `jsx-a11y` (Eg: `"jsx-a11y/rule-name": 2`).
4. Finally you can delete it from the project: `npm uninstall eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y --save-dev`.

PS: If you have any `disable` statement for `eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y`, remember to delete it (they won't be necessary anymore)

Answer (score -3):

Try to install the latest version of **react-scripts**

If this doesn't work, try updating all the way to the latest one 1.0.10, updated the react and react-dom in my package.json, deleted the package-lock.json and re-installed node_modules.

Comment: I think this is not really the solution that he is looking for (At least is not the scope of the question).

Comment: How does this address the question? OP is trying to remove the `eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y`.