# How to uninstall NPM modules from the devDependencies in node.js?

Tags: node.js, npm

How can I uninstall `npm` modules with devDependencies in Node.js?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to uninstall npm modules in node js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066532/how-to-uninstall-npm-modules-in-node-js)

Comment: Unless he is looking for `npm prune --production`. Maybe add this as a fifth point to your list?

Answer (score 39):

**Use command:**

1)`npm uninstall <name of the module>`

**Also you can use:**

1) `npm uninstall <name of the module>`: to remove the module from node_modules, but not package.json

2) `npm uninstall <name of the module> --save`: to also remove it from dependencies in package.json

3) `npm uninstall <name of the module> --save-dev`: to also remove it from devDependencies in package.json

4) `npm -g uninstall <name of the module> --save`: to remove it globally

Comment: I was new to this npm thing and these commands helped me to solved my issue. Great Job!

Answer (score 2):

###### For dev dependencies you can preform ***one***  -of- ***two*** commands, depending on your situation.

1. If you simply want to remove the dependency you can use the following.

   - ##### **`npm rm name-of-dependency`**

**TIP:** *If you forget how the name was spelled, check your `package.json` file under `"devDependencies"`.*

---

2. If you installed the dependency as a *"dev-dependency"*, and you decided after the fact that you wanted it installed as a regular *"dependency"* then you can simply install it using the `-S` flag, as shown below:

   - ##### **`npm i -S name-of-dependency`**

**TIP:** *It also works the other way around. To move a dependancy from the "dependencies" field in your `package.json` file, to the `"devDependencies"` field, swap out the `-S` flag for the `-D` flag.*

---

The install command `i` and the `rm` command (also the `-S` and `-D` flags) are currently the method that [NPM uses](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install#description) to document the process  for removing packages, and or changing a packages dependency type.

###### [SEE MORE ABOUT NPM CLI COMMANDS FOR INSTALLING & REMOVING PACKAGES HERE](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install#description)