# Laravel: How to Uninstall a dependency/plugin?

Tags: laravel, npm, dependencies

In the package.json I have these dependencies installed:

```
"dependencies": {
        "moment": "^2.24.0",
        "progressbar": "^1.3.0",
        "vue-progressbar": "^0.7.5",
        "vue-router": "^3.1.5"
    }
```

I need to remove `"progressbar": "^1.3.0"`.

How do I do this, please. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are your javascript dependencies, so with npm installed, you can simply use `npm uninstall progressbar --save` but refer to the [Documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/uninstall) or the accepted answer in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066532/how-to-uninstall-npm-modules-in-node-js) to find the optimal command for you

Comment: Awesome bro! Thanks a bunch! (sorry I'm trying to make an up vote but my reputations is too low.

Comment: Glad that helped.. and it's alright, you accepted the answer after all :)