# Right way uninstalling the NPM packages (Npm Uninstall vs Edit package.json)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have to remove several  libraries from the project. Currently worried about what if I remove a library, which is dependency of any other library.

Which approach can safely remove the libraries ?

I see I have two choices:

1. Edit package.json manually. Remove library entries... Delete node_modules folder and do npm install.
2. do npm uninstall --save for each package.

> What are difference between two, especially when I want to take one
> step at a time. Without breaking any peer dependencies

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I uninstall npm modules in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066532/how-can-i-uninstall-npm-modules-in-node-js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference at all

```
npm un package_name package_name ....
```

will uninstalls a package, completely removing everything npm installed on its behalf

It also removes the package from the `dependencies`, `devDependencies`, `optionalDependencies`, and `peerDependencies` objects in your `package.json` and update  `package-lock.json` file also

`--save` or `-S` will tell npm to remove the package from your `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files. This is the **default**, you don't have to use it.

`--no-save` is opposite to `--save` will tell npm not to remove but uninstall