# Is there a single command to synchronise npm packages in `package.json`?

Tags: node.js, npm

Let's say, I have install some new packages, uninstall some packages, update some packages to new versions. All changes are saved into `package.json`. When I pull the changes with this new `package.json`, is there a single command to do the synchronisation between the locally installed packages and those specified in the updated `package.json`?

I am looking for something like:

```
$ npm syncrhonise
```

Comment: npm install ? if the package.json has change the new package will install.

Comment: If it's removed in package.json, will the package be remove as well?

Comment: `npm update` did you try this?

Comment: no npm mange your repository. If you do same thing in this repository it is on your disk. if you want erase a package use npm uninstall [<@scope>/]<pkg>[@<version>]... [-S|--save|-D|--save-dev|-O|--save-optional]

Comment: `npm update` doesn't remove packages that are removed in package.json.

Comment: @hllau did you find my answer useful?

Answer (score 0):

`npm install` will install all packages specified in package.json. `npm update` will do the same but will also go a find any new versions of those packages. You can uninstall an individual package using `npm uninstall <package>`. There are already solutions to remove all packages [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19106284/how-do-you-uninstall-all-dependencies-listed-in-package-json-npm)

Comment: If I was you I would just delete your node modules folder then run `npm update`

Comment: Wouldn't it be wasting resources to download and fetch packages that are already installed again?

Comment: Depends how many packages you have. If you 2000 then maybe but otherwise who cares. Also npm caches quite a bit so you'd probably see a load of 304 codes if you ran the update

Comment: Some of the libraries require compilations. This is a workaround, but the speed will be very slow if I have to run this every time.

Answer (score 0):

I found two ways:

**First** `npm prune` will uninstall everything not listed in your package.json

> `npm prune [<name> [<name ...]]`
>
> This command removes "extraneous" packages. If a package name is
>   provided, then only packages matching one of the supplied names are
>   removed.
>
> Extraneous packages are packages that are not listed on the
>   parent package's dependencies list.

Documentation available at [prune](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/prune).

**Second** You could remove your node_modules/ folder and then reinstall the dependencies from package.json.

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install
```

> This would erase all installed packages in the current folder and only
>   install the dependencies from package.json. If the dependencies have
>   been previously installed npm will try to use the cached version,
>   avoiding downloading the dependency a second time.

**Windows Trick**

> Due to its folder nesting Windows can’t delete the folder as its name is too long. To solve this, install RimRaf:

```
npm install rimraf -g

rimraf node_modules
```