# Modal not working in React-Materialize

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, materialize

I'm trying to nest a modal component within the navbar component, but I come up with the following error:

```
Error: _processChildContext is not available in React 16+. This likely means you have multiple copies of React and are attempting to nest a React 15 tree inside a React 16 tree using unstable_renderSubtreeIntoContainer, which isn't supported. Try to make sure you have only one copy of React (and ideally, switch to ReactDOM.createPortal).
```

My code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Navbar, NavItem, Modal, Button } from 'react-materialize';


class Header extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showLoginModal: false
    };
    this.toggleLoginModal = this.toggleLoginModal.bind(this);
  }

  toggleLoginModal() {
    this.setState({ showLoginModal: !this.state.showLoginModal });
  }


  render() {
    console.log(this.state.showLoginModal);
    return (
    <div>
      <Navbar brand='Voting App' right>
        <Modal
          header='Login'
          trigger={<Button>Login</Button>}
        >
          Login
        </Modal>
      </Navbar>
    </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Header;
```

Any ideas why this is the case? Been trying to figure out the best way to introduce modals in react using the materialize styling, but hitting a lot of brick walls. Any help very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your yarn from 0.x to 1.x, or NPM accordingly and try it again. Based on this [post](https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/issues/1868) it should work.

Comment: I have the latest version of npm (5.4.2) and still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter with this problem, upgrading Yarn does not solve anything. You need to delete & re-install some conflicting packages. Upgrading yarn may delete those files, but if you are using npm; upgrading npm does not delete files and does not provide solution.

To delete modules:

If you use npm: [Command to remove all npm modules globally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283472/command-to-remove-all-npm-modules-globally)

If you use yarn: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1048