# If i uninstall node.js all npm packages will automatically uninstall?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have lot of issue with global and local NPM packages how do i manage.

I have tried each place go and uninstall but it  too TDS job. Planning to uninstall the Node.js and install it again will that help or not?

Question 1) How do i manage to delete all npm packages locally installed to uninstall

Question 2) i have uninstalled all npm packages globally. But NG command is not working after that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those using Windows, the easiest way to remove all globally installed npm packages is to delete the contents of:

C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm

You can get here quickly by typing %appdata% (either in explorer, run prompt, or start menu).

Bron: [Command to remove all npm modules globally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283472/command-to-remove-all-npm-modules-globally)

Comment: Globally removing has done but now the npm install is not working because of that