# Really removing all global npm modules

Tags: node.js, npm

I've just tried about every non-windows solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9283472/581205) and it indeed did something, but

```
npm ls -gp --depth=0.
```

returns

```
/usr/local/lib
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
```

and that entry seems to be immortal. One of the the commands I tried was

```
sudo npm ls -gp --depth=0 |
awk -F/ '/node_modules/ && !/\/npm$/ {print $NF}' |
xargs sudo npm -g rm
```

which now reports "up to date". I can see that in the end

```
sudo npm -g rm cli
```

gets executed, but does nothing (no idea if it should, I'm just trying to do a clean up to get a college's angular project running on my computer).

I've also tried variations with `uninstall` in place of `rm` and many other clueless approaches, but nothing changes.

Should I just nuke `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` or how else can I get rid of `cli`?

---

```
npm --version
5.6.0
```

Comment: I guess, I installed `npm` with `sudo`, which [is said to be wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354387/581205), but an uninstall should work anyway, shouldn't it?

Comment: you can remove every module form `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` manually.

Comment: @AnshumanJaiswal But there's also `/usr/local/bin/ng -> ../lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng` and possibly others....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module name is apparently `@angular/cli`, not just `cli`.   I also had this installed as a global module, and I was able to remove it (on Ubuntu 18.04) with:

```
sudo npm -g rm @angular/cli
```

Comment: I couldn't try it as I nuked my machine in the meantime, but it makes sense.