# NodeJS package confusion

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

In my `package.json` file, I have:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "chai-as-promised": "^7.0.0",
    "chai-bignumber": "^2.0.0",
    "decimal.js": "^10.0.0",
    "ethereumjs-testrpc-sc": "6.1.2",
    "ganache-cli": "6.1.0",
    "solidity-coverage": "0.4.14",
    "truffle": "4.1.3"
  }
```

I created a NodeJS script file `getWeb3Version.js`:

```
let web3 = require("web3");
console.log(web3.version);
```

When I run `node getWeb3Version.js` before `npm install`, I get `1.0.0-beta.30`.

When I run `node getWeb3Version.js` after `npm install`, I get `undefined`.

In order to investigate deeper, I changed `console.log(web3.version)` to `console.log(web3`), and it appears that the `web3` object after `npm install` is a very small subset of the `web3` object before `npm install`.

In order to investigate even deeper, I called `npm list --depth=0` from inside and from outside of my project folder (where the `package.json` file is located).

When I call `npm list --depth=0` from inside of my project folder, I get this:

```
+-- chai@4.1.2
+-- chai-as-promised@7.1.1
+-- chai-bignumber@2.0.2
+-- decimal.js@10.0.0
+-- ethereumjs-testrpc-sc@6.1.2
+-- ganache-cli@6.1.0
+-- solidity-coverage@0.4.14
`-- truffle@4.1.3
```

As you can see, `web3` is not even there (which is obvious, because I do not import it in my `package.json` file).

Nevertheless, `require("web3")` seems to work, as mentioned at the beginning of the question.

When I call `npm list --depth=0` from outside of my project folder, I get this:

```
+-- chai@4.1.2
+-- decimal.js@9.0.1
+-- ethereumjs-testrpc-sc@6.0.7
+-- ganache-cli@6.1.0
+-- log4js@2.5.2
+-- pug@2.0.0-rc.4
+-- solc@0.4.19
+-- solidity-coverage@0.4.14
+-- solidity-parser-sc@0.4.4
+-- sprintf-js@1.1.1
+-- testrpc@0.0.1
+-- truffle@4.1.7
`-- web3@1.0.0-beta.30
```

Followed by a bunch of lines starting with `npm ERR! extraneous:`.

What exactly is going on here?

Is it possible that one of the packages imported in my `package.json` file exports the subset of the `web3` object that I see when I do `console.log(web3)`?

Comment: I would list it as a dependency in my `package.json` to avoid any confusion, global modules are usually installed for clis and stuff like that,  in other cases it's better to specify modules in `package.json`

Comment: npm list will not give you full list. You can check `node_modules` folder, i bet you will have local version of `web3`.

Comment: @SunilBN: Thank you. I have `node_modules` inside my project folder (but I've explained about that one in my question, `web3` is not there). I have another one at `C:\Users\my_username`, and another one at `C:\Users\my_username\AppData\Roaming\npm`. And as you might guess, I am running on Windows. What exactly am I supposed to do with all of these?

Answer (score 1):

> `is a very small subset of the web3 object` is obtained after the
>   `npm install`

Is because, one of your installed module is using a different version of `web3`. And when you did not do an `npm install`, the `web3` package is obtained from the global packages which is `web3@1.0.0-beta.30`.

> The key thing to remember here is that that local package overrides
>   the global package.

Comment: Thank you. However, I have followed the instruction in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15597395), and removed all globally installed packages from my system. I admit that I do see yet another place where global packages might be located, at `C:\Users\my_username\node_modules`, so perhaps this answer is incomplete...

Comment: try `npm ls web3`, you will get more clarity.

Comment: When I do this outside my project folder, I get `web3@0.18.4  extraneous` under `solidity-coverage@0.4.14` and `web3@1.0.0-beta.30` at the top-level.
When I do this inside my project folder, I get `web3@0.18.4` under `solidity-coverage@0.4.14`.

Comment: this command lists both the ones available outside and inside, as you have deleted the global modules, you will only get one, that is the one installed by the `npm install`. If you try to use the module now after deleting your node_modules, it will throw man error now

Answer (score 0):

If the package is not listed in your dependencies and you are still able to use it, it may be because it is installed globally. 
You can check whether it is installed globally by doing `npm ls -g`
Also unlike chai,ganache-cli,  web3 is an application dependency so try to find it on depemdencies instead of dev dependencies