# Npm install rebuilds .node-gyp upon every install

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp, fsevents

I'm getting this message upon every `npm install`:

```
> fsevents@1.2.4 install /Users/USERNAME/URL/TO/GULP/FILE/node_modules/fsevents
> node install

[fsevents] Success: "/Users/USERNAME/URL/TO/GULP/FILE/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v57-darwin-x64/fse.node" already installed
Pass --update-binary to reinstall or --build-from-source to recompile

> node-sass@3.13.1 install /Users/USERNAME/URL/TO/GULP/FILE/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/darwin-x64-57_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/darwin-x64-57_binding.node":

HTTP error 404 Not Found

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

> node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall /Users/USERNAME/URL/TO/GULP/FILE/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: /usr/local/bin/node /Users/USERNAME/URL/TO/GULP/FILE/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
gyp verb cli   '/Users/USERNAME/URL/TO/GULP/FILE/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.7.0
gyp info using node@8.11.1 | darwin | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/Users/USERNAME/URL/TO/GULP/FILE/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/Users/USERNAME/URL/TO/GULP/FILE/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/Users/USERNAME/URL/TO/GULP/FILE/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/USERNAME/URL/TO/GULP/FILE/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/USERNAME/URL/TO/GULP/FILE/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/USERNAME/URL/TO/GULP/FILE/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 { Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/Users/USERNAME/URL/TO/GULP/FILE/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/Users/USERNAME/URL/TO/GULP/FILE/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/Users/USERNAME/URL/TO/GULP/FILE/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/USERNAME/URL/TO/GULP/FILE/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/USERNAME/URL/TO/GULP/FILE/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/USERNAME/URL/TO/GULP/FILE/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python2\n    at getNotFoundError (/Users/USERNAME/URL/TO/GULP/FILE/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)\n    at F (/Users/USERNAME/URL/TO/GULP/FILE/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)\n    at E (/Users/USERNAME/URL/TO/GULP/FILE/node_modules/    which/which.js:80:29)\n    at /Users/USERNAME/URL/TO/GULP/FILE/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16\n    at /Users/USERNAME/URL/TO/GULP/FILE/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5\n    at /Users/USERNAME/URL/TO/GULP/FILE/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5\n    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python /usr/bin/python
gyp verb check python version `/usr/bin/python -c "import platform; print(platform.python_version());"` returned: "2.7.10\n"
gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 8.11.1
gyp verb command install [ '8.11.1' ]
gyp verb install input version string "8.11.1"
gyp verb install installing version: 8.11.1
gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
gyp verb install version is good
gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 8.11.1
gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /Users/USERNAME/URL/TO/GULP/FILE/node_modules/node-sass/build
gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? /Users/USERNAME/URL/TO/GULP/FILE/node_modules/node-sass/build
gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: /Users/USERNAME/URL/TO/GULP/FILE/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi
gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: /Users/USERNAME/URL/TO/GULP/FILE/node_modules/node-sass/config.gypi
gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: /Users/USERNAME/URL/TO/GULP/FILE/node_modules/node-sass/common.gypi
gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "make"
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python
gyp info spawn args [ '/Users/USERNAME/URL/TO/GULP/FILE/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/USERNAME/URL/TO/GULP/FILE/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/USERNAME/URL/TO/GULP/FILE/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/USERNAME/.node-gyp/8.11.1/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/USERNAME/.node-gyp/8.11.1',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/USERNAME/URL/TO/GULP/FILE/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/USERNAME/.node-gyp/8.11.1/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/USERNAME/URL/TO/GULP/FILE/node_modules/node-sass',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
gyp verb command build []
gyp verb build type Release
gyp verb architecture x64
gyp verb node dev dir /Users/USERNAME/.node-gyp/8.11.1
gyp verb `which` succeeded for `make` /usr/bin/make
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'V=1', 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
  c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.3.6"' -I/Users/USERNAME/.node-gyp/8.11.1/include/node -I/Users/    USERNAME/.node-gyp/8.11.1/src -I/Users/USERNAME/.node-gyp/8.11.1/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/USERNAME/.node-gyp/8.11.1/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/USERNAME/.node-gyp/8.11.1/deps/uv/include -I/Users/USERNAME/.node-gyp/8.11.1/deps/zlib -I/Users/USERNAME/.node-gyp/8.11.1/deps/    v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-threadsafe-statics -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o.d.raw       -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o ../src/libsass/src/ast.cpp
^Cmake: *** Deleting file `Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o'
make: *** [Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o] Interrupt: 2
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN GulpFileName@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN GulpFileName@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

My global installed packages ( `npm -g ls --depth=0` ) are these:

```
/usr/local/lib
├── fsevents@1.2.4
├── gulp@3.9.1
├── gulp-cli@2.0.1
├── jscs@3.0.7
├── n@2.1.8
├── node-gyp@3.7.0
├── node-sass@4.9.0
├── npm@5.10.0
└── vue-cli@2.9.3
```

The errors come when I run `npm install` with this `package.json`-file:

```
{
    "name": "GulpName",
    "author": "Johnny Bravo",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "license": "GPL-2.0",
    "dependencies": {},
    "devDependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "^8.6.3",
        "browserslist": "^3.2.8",
        "gulp": "^4.0.0",
        "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
        "gulp-postcss": "^7.0.1",
        "gulp-sass": "^2.0.0",
        "gulp-clean-css": "^3.9.4",
        "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.0"
    },
    "browserslist": [
        "last 2 version",
        "> 1%",
        "safari >= 5",
        "ie >= 8",
        "chrome >= 34",
        "ie_mob >= 10",
        "opera >= 23",
        "ios >= 7",
        "ff >= 7",
        "android >= 4",
        "bb >= 10"
    ]
}
```

### My attempts:

- I tried removing `~/.node-gyp` (and then refreshing the cache with `npm cache verify`).
- I tried uninstalling all the 'random' packages I could see with `npm -g ls --depth=0`. I had some `phantomjs` and a `http-server` or something like that.
- I tried installing `node-gyp`, `fsevents` and `node-sass` globally, hoping that I shouldn't go through those steps in the install-procedure. But I still get the same long error.

... And obviously I did `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json` followed by `npm install` a bazillion times throughout my attempt of solving this.

I can see [several](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/809) [places](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1991#issuecomment-306437979), something about people who gets similar errors, which is due to some yarn-thingy. I've haven't used any such thing.

Do I really have to endure this tedious and long install-procedure every time I run `npm install`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok... I figured most of it our myself. The problem was that `node-sass` had version `"~2.0.0"`, which was too old. When I bumped that up to `"4.0.1"`, then the recompiling of `node-gyp` went away.

Here was my process, though - for the rookies who want to try some things themselves:

1. Remember that you have your local packages (in `package.json`) and your global packages (accessed by writing: `npm -g ls --depth=0`.
2. You can remove all of your global packages, by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9283646/1766219).
3. Then remove your devDependencies one at the time, and try running `npm install` until the stupid error goes away.

I'm still getting this error (which I wont solve, since I decreased my `npm install`-time by a minute or so, which is enough for me).

```
> fsevents@1.2.4 install /PATH/TO/PACKAGEJSON-FILE/node_modules/fsevents
> node install

[fsevents] Success: "/PATH/TO/PACKAGEJSON-FILE/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v57-darwin-x64/fse.node" already installed
Pass --update-binary to reinstall or --build-from-source to recompile

> node-sass@4.9.0 install /PATH/TO/PACKAGEJSON-FILE/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Cached binary found at /Users/REDACTED/.npm/node-sass/4.9.0/darwin-x64-57_binding.node

> node-sass@4.9.0 postinstall /PATH/TO/PACKAGEJSON-FILE/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Binary found at /PATH/TO/PACKAGEJSON-FILE/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-57/binding.node
Testing binary
Binary is fine
```

Comment: My issue was the same also, with node-sass. I updated from version: ^4.13.1 -> ^4.14.1 and it worked all fine. thanks

Answer (score 0):

so spent few hours with similar problem. tried with installed node v19,v18,v16  and all other tries like reinstall python node-gyp versions ... solution was to set **node v14 and npm install** fixed everything!