# whether the npm uninstall * command will remove the global installs too while uninstalling the dependencies of package.json or not?

Tags: node.js, npm, alibaba-cloud, alibaba-cloud-ecs

My application is hosted in Alibaba Cloud ECS Instance and I am trying to uninstall the dependencies of the package.json. I understand the `npm uninstall *` command will uninstall all the dependencies but the question is whether it will remove global installs too or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is no uninstalling with a wildcard like `npm uninstall *` command in npm. The issue is still being opened here https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19967.

Use this command to uninstall your global dependencies :

`npm ls -gp --depth=0 | awk -F/ '/node_modules/ && !/\/npm$/ {print $NF}' | xargs npm -g rm`

reference: [Command to remove all npm modules globally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283472/command-to-remove-all-npm-modules-globally/19357869)

Answer (score 0):

To uninstall a global package, type: `npm uninstall -g <package>`. 
It has the extra flag `-g` for global.