# NPM Global Install Fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, npm

The global install of this CLI started failing and I'm not sure why.

```
git clone https://github.com/superflycss/cli
cd cli
npm i -g
```

The log file is 10K lines log, but this is what it says at the end:

```
    7353 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/ole/.nvm/versions/node/v11.0.0/lib/node_modules/.staging/@superflycss/cli-5549c074/node_modules/@babel/code-frame' -> '/home/ole/.nvm/versions/node/v11.0.0/lib/node_modules/.staging/@babel/code-frame-78217d7a'
    7354 verbose cwd /home/ole/SuperflyCSS/cli
    7355 verbose Linux 4.15.0-45-generic
    7356 verbose argv "/home/ole/.nvm/versions/node/v11.0.0/bin/node" "/home/ole/.nvm/versions/node/v11.0.0/bin/npm" "i" "-g"
    7357 verbose node v11.0.0
    7358 verbose npm  v6.7.0
    7359 error path /home/ole/.nvm/versions/node/v11.0.0/lib/node_modules/.staging/@superflycss/cli-5549c074/node_modules/@babel/code-frame
    7360 error code ENOENT
    7361 error errno -2
    7362 error syscall rename
    7363 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/ole/.nvm/versions/node/v11.0.0/lib/node_modules/.staging/@superflycss/cli-5549c074/node_modules/@babel/code-frame' -> '/home/ole/.nvm/versions/node/v11.0.0/lib/node_modules/.staging/@babel/code-frame-78217d7a'
    7364 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
    7365 verbose exit [ -2, true ]
```

[I've tried removing all global modules per the instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283472/command-to-remove-all-npm-modules-globally) and then reinstalling.  However it still fails, even with a complete local module refresh (Nuke local `node_modules`).

Also tried:

sudo rm -fr /home/ole/.npm-packages/*

And then `npm i -g` and the result is still the same.

### Update

I think it might be this bug:

https://npm.community/t/global-installs-sudo-npm-i-g-fail-on-mac-after-6-5-upgrade-works-fine-after-6-4-1-downgrade/4082/15

Comment: What is the version do you use of NPM?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to install everything in package.json globally? Seems kind of odd...

Comment: I'm the developer of the CLI.  I have Jest unit tests, but occasionally I perform a local global install in order to do local testing manually.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try installing the superflycss CLI globally with npm through the npmjs registry as opposed to cloning the superflycss repository and trying to  build from source. For example:

```
npm i -g @superflycss/cli
```

then just use it like so:

```
  Usage: sfc [options] [command]
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: I also do that - But I'm the author of the CLI, so I need to be able to install locally for dev purposes.

Answer (score 0):

```
docker run -it node bash
git clone https://github.com/superflycss/cli
cd cli
npm i -g
```

Works just fine!

```
root@c3adb3ae08aa:/cli# sfc --version
1.0.0
root@c3adb3ae08aa:/cli# sfc --help
Usage: sfc [options] [command]

SuperflyCSS Command Line Interface
[more stuff here]
```

Try clearing your node_modules global cache and local dir.

Comment: I updated the question with the step I did for removing global modules.  I wonder if it has something to do with npm version 6.7.0 ... I think this started to happen after I installed that.  It was working fine for me too.

Comment: I'm also using this (npm i -g without sudo): https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md

Answer (score -1):

Fixed this by upgrading to node v11.9.0 and NPM v6.7.0.