# How to display all installed npm packages and delete them

Tags: node.js, npm, nodemailer

**I would like to display all my installed npm packages (nodemailer, json, etc) and delete them. Also, I would like to clean npm "history".**

I have read that I should do this:
`npm list -g`
to display all packages but I am not sure this is exactly it because I have recently downloaded nodemailer and it is not in this list...

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-
it removes all global npm modules. Note: this does not work on Windows.

```
npm ls -gp --depth=0 | awk -F/ '/node_modules/ && !/\/npm$/ {print $NF}' | xargs npm -g rm
```

**For Windows in a directory**

refer this [medim article to delete node modules in a folder](https://medium.com/@MarkPieszak/how-to-delete-all-node-modules-folders-on-your-machine-and-free-up-hd-space-f3954843aeda)

if this doesn't work for you refer this
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283472/command-to-remove-all-npm-modules-globally#:~:text=If%20you%20would%20like%20to,g%20rm%20to%20remove%20them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283472/command-to-remove-all-npm-modules-globally#:%7E:text=If%20you%20would%20like%20to,g%20rm%20to%20remove%20them).

Comment: I have windows... Anyway, I actually would like to delete packages in this directory: npm list --depth

Comment: i have updated my answer for windows( to delete for a particular folder)
and that stack link have answer for windows too :)